# How to check input in Javascript for input type=text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fill a table with random numbers and then have a user complete the totals.  After entering the totals I wanted to check the answers, if the answer is correct I wanted to no longer allow input if the answer was wrong I wanted the cell highlighted and allow the user to try again.

The table is filling and incorrect answers are being identified however further attempts to modify the answers don't give any feedback.  I am not sure why the input button can't be used multiple times I am guessing something needs to be cleared to accept another entry.  I am just playing with JS so this is probably something very simple but I haven't been able to find a working solution.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Testing</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,800,700,600,300'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var ran = new Array(4);
var count = 0;

function randomArray ( )
{
    count = 0;
    var max = 10;
    var min = 5;

    for ( var i = 0; i < ran.length; ++i)
    {
        ran[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1) + min);
    }
    iter = Math.floor(Math.random()*(4));
    iter2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(4));


}

function fillRandom(id)
{

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ran[count];
    count++;

}

function check(id, id2, i, j)
{

    var ans = document.getElementById(id).value.toString();
    var soln = document.getElementById(id2);


    //document.getElementById(id2).style.border = "thick red double";
    if (ans != (ran[i] + ran[j]))
    {
        soln.style.border = "thick red double";
        correct = false;

    }
    else
    {
        soln.innerHTML = (ran[i] + ran[j]);
        correct = true;


    }

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>

<input type="submit" value="Get Questions" onclick="randomArray();fillRandom('num1');fillRandom('num2');fillRandom('num3');fillRandom('num4');"/>
<p>Try the following questions:</p>

<table  id="data" border="thin black">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="A">A</td>
    <td id="B">B</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="C">C</td>
    <td id="num1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="num2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="t12"><input id="total_1_2" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="D">D</td>
    <td id="num3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="num4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="t34"><input id="total_3_4" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="t13" ><input type="text" id="total_1_3"/></td>
    <td id="t24"><input type="text" id="total_2_4"/></td>
    <td id="t"><input type="text" id="total"/></td>
</tr>

</table>


<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Check Total" onclick="check('total_1_2', 't12', '0', '1');check('total_3_4', 't34', '2', '3');check('total_1_3', 't13', '0', '2');
    check('total_2_4', 't24', '1', '3')">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals

Comment: `<input type="submit" ...>` change to `<input type="button" ...>`

Comment: Changing to <input type="button" ... > still doesn't let me update all fields if they are all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function check(id, id2, i, j)
{

    var ans ;
    if(document.getElementById(id) !== null)
        ans = document.getElementById(id).value;
    else
        ans = document.getElementById(id2).textContent;

    var soln = document.getElementById(id2);

    if (ans != (ran[i] + ran[j]))
    {
        soln.style.border = "thick red double";
        correct = false;    
    }
    else
    {
        soln.innerHTML = (ran[i] + ran[j]);
         soln.style.border = "none";
        correct = true;        
    }    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6zhL/

Answer (score 0):

When you correct an entry and click on “Check Total”, the code now turns the `input` element to content consisting of the user data, but it does not change the cell border. The border was set to `thick red double`, and nothing changes that. A minimal fix would be to edit that part of the `if` statement in the `check` function so that normal border is set: `soln.style.border = "solid thin black";`.

However, there is much else to be fixed in the design. Now if you enter several incorrect answers and fix one of them, then click on “Check Total”, you will see an error message in the console log. The reason is that the checking code tries to get the user data from `input` elements, even in the cell that now contains no `input` element. So you may need to modify the logic so that `input` elements are not removed or so that `input` elements that were removed are also removed from the set of elements to be checked.

Comment: That makes more sense.  I wasn't exactly sure what the input element was doing.  I will try to modify the logic and see if it gets me any closer.  Thanks